# Why hasn't anybody built a free bibliographic database yet?

Tags: citations, databases

A globally available, free bibliographic database, much like Google Scholar but with stronger query-building and export of hits, would be tremendously useful.

[Edited to add explanation of why this would be useful: Specifically, systematic reviews and meta-analyses require replicable procedures. This means queries must be repeatable (yielding the same hits) and hits must be exportable to enable e.g. double-blind, documentable screening procedures. Ideally these procedures and their replications are Open (i.e. inclusive to all researchers), and so expensive licenses can be undesirable.

To clarify what I mean by queries and exporting: e.g. a systematic review could use a query like:

```
(TI:("condom use" OR "safe sex") OR
  AB:("condom use" OR "safe sex")) AND
(TI:(determinants* OR "psycho-social variables") OR
  AB:(determinants* OR "psycho-social variables"))
```

Which would look for all papers that include either 'condom use' or 'safe sex' (or both) in their title or abstract, and also include either 'determinants' or 'psycho-social variables' (or both) in their title or abstract.

The next step would then be to export all hits to enable screening of the hundreds or thousands of references for relevance (ideally by two or more blinded screeners).

Google Scholar has very limited query-building capacities and no exporting functionalities (i.e. it does for single hits, but not for thousands of hits in one go).

However, no such freely available systems seem to exist.

Is there some reason for this other than that nobody has got around to it yet? Are there license problems? The title, authors etc are not copyrighted I think, but maybe abstracts are - on the other hand abstracts etc are all in the public domain, so I assume they can be copied, emailed to colleagues, etc, and so I guess they could be included in such a database as well. Or is that not allowed?

Comment: In my field (computer engineering), IEEE and ACM (if I'm not mistaken) allow papers/abstracts to be emailed between colleagues for personal use only (unless you pay a rather large fee) -- what you're proposing would most likely violate that. But more to the point: I imagine it has to do with the fact that Google Scholar/individual databases already more or less provide what researchers want/need. You can search pretty much any database (at least any database I can think of) for free -- it's accessing the actual papers contained within that costs $$.

Comment: What do you mean by "_with stronger query-building and export of hits_"? Please clarify.

Comment: Apart from breadth of coverage, would PubMed qualify? PubMed is a pretty big thing and going even bigger seems hard.

Comment: Since you make it sound so easy, perhaps you could throw it together this weekend?

Comment: [DBLP](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/) is a free bibliographic database that covers at least 90% of the computer science literature.  There are similar databases in other fields.

Comment: Do you enjoy working for free?

Comment: The last sentence of this question contradicts itself by saying that abstracts might be protected by copyright but are in the public domain.

Comment: @scaaahu, I've attempted to clarify the issue further.

Comment: @tonysdg: I hope the clarification helps to explain this, too.

Comment: @StrongBad: yes, PubMed is a good example, but as you imply, quite narrow in its focus. Curious why nothing broader exists yet.

Comment: @JonCuster, I don't think this is easy - but it's definitely *doable* (not by one person, but by an organisation).

Comment: @JeffE: Thanks - is there an index of those somewhere?

Comment: @CapeCode: yes, depending on the work.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I'm not sure which it is...

Comment: http://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/public-domain/welcome/

Comment: Voted to re-open and upvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[I4OC: the Initiative for Open Citations](https://i4oc.org/)**

This is probably the leading project to do this, though I believe there have been various proposals in the past.

> The idea of creating an advocacy group to promote the availability of citation data gained momentum at the 8th Conference on Open Access Scholarly Publishing (COASP 2016), in response to a report that only a tiny minority of the almost 1,000 publishers depositing references with Crossref at that time were making this data publicly available.

They're making pretty good progress:

> As of June 2017, the fraction of publications with open references has grown from 1% to more than 45% out of the nearly 35 million articles with references deposited with Crossref (to date).

However, there's a long way still to go - not least that the 35m target quoted there is only articles in Crossref, which means ones for which a DOI has been issued. Once you get into historical material which never made it online, this can potentially get a lot more challenging; I'm not familiar with how (or whether) they plan to address legacy material.

And, of course, it's only targeting the underlying data. They haven't made a move to build a "user-friendly" database on top of it, though there's nothing preventing a third party from doing so.

Comment: That is pretty good coverage, and indeed, although they provide no interface yet, it's a great start!!! In fact, for replicable research, using scripts and e.g. the R package 'rcrossref' is preferable over using a "user-friendly" interface. So people *are* working on this - it is not only doable, but being done :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is that there is no real need for such a (locally stored) database. Currently the Web itself is used as the ''database'' for bibliographic information, and the Web, through Google, allows all users to have very good querying mechanism.

Comment: I hope the extra explanation makes a bit clearer what I meant, sorry for the initial vague question!